# couldnt recognise pom.xml file

Tags: maven-2, build-process

i am build forge as build tool. it is executing maven mvn commands fine ,but it couldnt recognizing the maven project pom.xml to run the build.so i tried to execute the same pom.xml through the command window and that is working fine could any one can help me how to solve the issue

i am using maven 2.09 version and build forge 7.1

is there any compatibility issues with maven if so what are they

thanks Dagg

Comment: How is a build triggered with Build Forge? I mean, does it spawn a shell and run the `mvn` command?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure you'll find more Build Forge knowledge here on SO (but I may be wrong) than on the forum where you posted the same [question](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14385767&#14385767) :) Build Forge doesn't seem to be very popular actually (and its forums not very active). That said, according to [this message](https://www.ibm.com/developerworks/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=14059416), it should be possible to *kick off a maven project* but, according to other messages from the same thread, the support seems limited and you are "on your own".

In your case, my guess is that maven is not started in the right "working directory" (or it should be able to find the pom). But this is just a guess, I don't have any BF knowledge (lucky me).

To be honest, you should consider talking to your IBM commercial guy or to IBM support or, if this is an option, just using something else than BF unless it's really providing value. Maybe your organization will thank you after all.